# New Year Untagged cleanup

Tags: discussion, cleanup

I'm opening this post to collect some feedback/help about my current attempt at cleaning up the remaining untagged questions on the main site.

As you may have noticed, almost any question that gets migrated to the site ends up as untagged (because almost all where originally tagged "SharePoint 20__", aka the One Evil Tag of Doom). Also sometime old question ends up as untagged because some old tags gets pruned (low usage).

I have cleaned up the most obvius ones... but there are stil some questions that need clean up. I was wondering if anyone could try to [have a look](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and see if any appropiate tags comes to mind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 yay! Also on my list to clean up are questions tagged [tag:sharepoint-enterprise] or [tag:sharepoint-foundation]. These are worse than that major version tags.

Comment: Great job! Thanks for doing this.

Comment: No need to thank me. I have started doing this after I noticed that migrated question are simply bound to end up as untagged. Most of the time finding an appropiate tag is pretty easy, but there are some question that still make me wonder... Thake this [two](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15228/where-can-i-find-a-presentation-on-sharepoint-to-encourage-management-buy-in) [questions](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/the-sharepoint-2010-logo-high-res-version) - the only tag I can think of would be "Marketing", and I am not sure I want to create it...

Comment: I would think Image would be acceptable or logo so that a new tag doesn't need to be created.

Comment: You think so? IMHO that would be a little missleading: if I perform a search for the tag "Image" I would expect results related to image usage, like broken images in sites, image libraries and so on. [That question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1483/the-sharepoint-2010-logo-high-res-version) only seems to indicate a marketing/advertising problem. I'm not sure that I would want to tag it simply as image.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Perhaps "recommendations" would fit?

Comment: @StuartPegg - sorry, didn't see your comment before (where did the notify go?). Anyway, yes... "recommendations/suggestions" would seem a good guess.. and it would match other question as well. Will see if anything better comes to mind, but for now your suggestion imho is the best one.